# Getting the value of checkbox from the table cell using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to obtain the value of the checkbox when "expand" is clicked, I have tried the following this looks clumsy and when the DOM is modified then it may render undefined instead of the expect value CBVALUE

```
<tr>
    <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="CBVALUE" id="r0"></td>
    <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="rGjgODop0">Somevalue</a></td>
    <td class="third"><a class="option s" id="option_0">Expand</a> <a href=""></a></td>
    <td class="fourth">2018-08-31T08:25:09.617Z</td>
</tr>
```

```js
$('.option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().prev().prev().children().first().val()); //should alert as CBVALUE 
});
```

Is there an easier solution than traversing with relative elements?

Comment: $('.option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().find('input.selects').val()); //should alert as CBVALUE 
});

Answer (score 2):

You can try below logic where find parent `tr` and then find `checkbox` to read value

```js
$(function(){
$('.option').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').val();
    alert(value);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="CBVALUE" id="r0"></td>
    <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="rGjgODop0">Somevalue</a></td>
    <td class="third"><a class="option s" id="option_0">Expand</a> <a href=""></a></td>
    <td class="fourth">2018-08-31T08:25:09.617Z</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`$(...).siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method and pass it a selector:

```js
$('.option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).siblings("#r0[type='checkbox']").val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
    <td class="first"><input class="selects" type="checkbox" value="CBVALUE" id="r0"></td>
    <td class="second"><a target="_blank" href="rGjgODop0">Somevalue</a></td>
    <td class="third"><a class="option s" id="option_0">Expand</a> <a href=""></a></td>
    <td class="fourth">2018-08-31T08:25:09.617Z</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$.parents()` instead:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').val()
```

Comment: `closest()` is preferable to `parents()` in this case as it stops at the first match`

Answer (score 1):

for me, .find() method seems to return an array of checkbox objects, I need to add [0] to the end to be able to apply .val() method, otherwise I got 'on' all times. Example:

`var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox')[0].val()`

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do by using filtering. See this demo [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qwcyr8zd/76/)

```
$(this).closest('td').parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').val()
```